# Connect to a paired device without user permission in Chrome web bluetooth API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-bluetooth, webusb

By using the API navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(), a web page could ask a user for his permission to pair and establish connection with a bluetooth device. After approving the request, assume the user reloads the web page. Is there a way for the web to connect to that paired device without asking for permission again?

I know we can do that in web-usb with API navigator.usb.getDevices(), but I can not find a way to do that in web-bluetooth. Anyone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Web Bluetooth specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#permission-api-integration) mentions that the `navigator.permissions.query()` method can be used to request `BluetoothDevice` objects for which permission was granted prior to a page reload.

However, Chrome does not currently implement persistent Web Bluetooth permissions the way that is done for WebUSB nor does it implement querying Web Bluetooth permissions through the `navigator.permission` API. Both of these tasks are tracked by [issue 577953](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=577953).